# grep and gsub to find patterns and call out patterns

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, gsub

I'm trying to search text for keywords and then pull back the keywords that it finds.

right now I'm at / reproducible example:

```
text <- c("Here is some text about cats and dogs",
          "Here is some text about turtles and chickens",
          "Here is some text about rhinos and elephants")
pattern <- "cat|turtle"
HasPattern <- as.vector(NULL)
for(i in 1:length(text)){
if(sum(grepl(pattern, text[i], ignore.case = TRUE)>0))
   HasPattern <- append(HasPattern, text[i])
}
```

The desired result for this output would be:

```
gsub(grepl(pattern, text), pattern, text) # or something
[1] cat turtle NA
```

I've tried --

```
for (i in 1:length(text)){
  if(grepl(pattern, text[i]) == TRUE)
     gsub(text[i], pattern, text[i])
}


sub(text, pattern, text)

gsub(grepl(pattern, text), pattern, text)
```

In the reproducible example:
HasPattern gives me a vector of the texts that have what I want which is great. But I would also like a vector of what pattern it found in those texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text, pattern)
#[1] "cat"    "turtle" NA
```

Comment: @MattW.  You can make the changes in the pattern to make it case insensitive

Comment: How is that usually done? "Cat|cat" is the only way I know but I have a large list for a pattern.

Comment: @MattW  Suppose You want to extract it, then `str_extract(text, "(?i)(C)at|turtle")`

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform `regmatches` along with `gregexpr` in baseR

```
regmat <- regmatches(text,gregexpr(pattern,text))
regmat[lapply(regmat , length) == 0] <- NA 
unlist(regmat)
```

Output:

```
> unlist(regmat)
[1] "cat"    "turtle" NA
```